# Check consistency of statements, with fuzzy rhyme matching (Kattis "Mårten's Theorem" challenge)

Tags: python, programming-challenge, rags-to-riches

I wrote a review for [Check consistency of a list of statements, with fuzzy rhyme matching](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/156854/9357), which basically required me to try writing my own solution to fully understand the challenge.  So, I thought that I should put my solution up for review.

I'll paraphrase the ["Mårten's Theorem" challenge on Kattis](https://open.kattis.com/problems/more10):

> Given up to 100000 statements of the form `X is Y` or `X not Y`, determine whether the statements are consistent (in which case output `yes`) or inconsistent (in which case output `wait what?`).  `X` and `Y` are words, up to 20 characters long.  For example, the two statements `ulf is lukas` and `ulf not lukas` contradict each other.  The three statements `ulf is lukas` and `lukas is ulf` and `ulf is bjorn`, however, could be consistent.
>
> The catch is that every word that rhymes with *X* in any provided statement is said to be equivalent to *X*. Here, two words `X` and `Y` are said to "rhyme" if the last `min(3, |X|, |Y|)` characters are the same.
>
> Some examples:
>
> ```
> 4
> herp is derp
> derp is herp
> herp is herp
> derp is derp
> ```
>
> Output to the input above should be `yes`.
>
> ---
>
> ```
> 3
> oskar not lukas
> oskar is poptart
> lukas is smart
> ```
>
> … should output `wait what?`, because:
>
> - you could infer that `lukas is poptart` (due to rhyming equivalence between `poptart` and `smart`)
> - you could also infer that `lukas is oskar` (since `lukas is poptart` and `oskar is poptart`)
> - that contradicts `oskar not lukas`.
>
> ---
>
> ```
> 1
> moo not foo
> ```
>
> … should output `yes`
>
> ---
>
> ```
> 2
> moo not foo
> oo is blah
> ```
>
> … should output `wait what?`, because the appearance of the word `oo` anywhere means that the first statement `moo not foo` could be equivalent to `oo not oo`, which is a self-contradiction.

---

I wrote a solution in Python 3, but I believe it also works in Python 2.  I've attempted to address all of the issues I pointed out in [this review](/a/156879/9357).

```
import fileinput
from itertools import chain
import re

def read_rules(line_iter, word_suffix_len=3):
    r"""
    Read the rules into a dictionary of two sets.  Only the last
    word_suffix_len letters of each word are considered.

    >>> rules = read_rules('''3
    ... oskar not lukas
    ... oskar is poptart
    ... lukas is smart'''.split('\n'))
    >>> rules == {
    ...     'is': set([('kar', 'art'), ('kas', 'art')]),
    ...     'not': set([('kar', 'kas')]),
    ... }
    True
    """
    rules = {'is': set(), 'not': set()}
    regex = re.compile(r'.*?(\S{1,%d}) (is|not) .*?(\S{1,%d})$' % (word_suffix_len, word_suffix_len))
    line_iter = iter(line_iter)
    for _ in range(int(next(line_iter))):
        line = next(line_iter)
        match = regex.match(line)
        if match is None:
            raise Exception('Invalid input: ' + line)
        rules[match.group(2)].add((match.group(1), match.group(3)))
    return rules

def subst_rule_words(rules, word_map={}):
    """
    Make a copy of the rules with the word substitutions applied.

    >>> rules = {
    ...     'is': set([('one', 'won'), ('two', 'too'), ('foo', 'bar')]),
    ...     'not': set([('one', 'wun'), ('six', 'sex')]),
    ... }
    >>> r = subst_rule_words(rules, {'one': 'un', 'two': 'deux', 'wun': 'baz'})
    >>> r == {
    ...     'is': set([('un', 'won'), ('deux', 'too'), ('foo', 'bar')]),
    ...     'not': set([('un', 'baz'), ('six', 'sex')]),
    ... }
    True
    """
    simplified_rules = {}
    for rule_type, statements in rules.items():
        simplified_rules[rule_type] = set(
            tuple(word_map.get(word, word) for word in words)
            for words in statements
        )
    return simplified_rules

def rhyme_map(rules, word_suffix_len=3):
    """
    Make a map of word substitutions based on shared word endings.

    >>> rules = {'not': [('moo', 'foo')], 'is': [('oo', 'blah')]}
    >>> rhyme_map(rules) == {'foo': 'oo', 'moo': 'oo'}
    True
    """
    words = set(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(rules.values())))
    abbreviations = {}
    short_words = set()
    for word_len in range(1, word_suffix_len + 1):
        for word in (w for w in words if len(w) == word_len):
            for short_word in short_words:
                if word.endswith(short_word):
                    abbreviations[word] = short_word
            if word_len < word_suffix_len:
                short_words.add(word)
    return abbreviations

def union_map(rules):
    """
    Make a map of word substitutions based on the "is" rules.
    This is an implementation of union-find.
    """
    uf = UnionFind()
    for x, y in rules['is']:
        uf.union(x, y)
    equivs = {x: uf[x] for x, y in rules['is']}
    equivs.update({y: uf[y] for x, y in rules['is']})
    return equivs

def main(fileinput):
    r"""
    >>> main('''4
    ... herp is derp
    ... derp is herp
    ... herp is herp
    ... derp is derp'''.split('\n'))
    yes

    >>> main('''3
    ... oskar not lukas
    ... oskar is poptart
    ... lukas is smart'''.split('\n'))
    wait what?

    >>> main('''1
    ... moo not foo'''.split('\n'))
    yes

    >>> main('''2
    ... moo not foo
    ... oo is blah'''.split('\n'))
    wait what?
    """
    rules = read_rules(fileinput)
    if rules['not']:    # Ruleset without "not" rules must be self-consistent
        rules = subst_rule_words(rules, rhyme_map(rules))
        rules = subst_rule_words(rules, union_map(rules))
    print('wait what?' if any(x == y for x, y in rules['not']) else 'yes')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(fileinput.input())
```

---

In the `union_map` function, I am making use of an [MIT-licensed](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/PADS/ABOUT-PADS.txt) implementation of the [union-find data structure by David Eppstein](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~eppstein/PADS/UnionFind.py).  I have included it below for reference, but it is not subject to review here.

> ```
> """UnionFind.py
>
> Union-find data structure. Based on Josiah Carlson's code,
> http://aspn.activestate.com/ASPN/Cookbook/Python/Recipe/215912
> with significant additional changes by D. Eppstein.
> """
>
> class UnionFind:
>     """Union-find data structure.
>
>     Each unionFind instance X maintains a family of disjoint sets of
>     hashable objects, supporting the following two methods:
>
>     - X[item] returns a name for the set containing the given item.
>       Each set is named by an arbitrarily-chosen one of its members; as
>       long as the set remains unchanged it will keep the same name. If
>       the item is not yet part of a set in X, a new singleton set is
>       created for it.
>
>     - X.union(item1, item2, ...) merges the sets containing each item
>       into a single larger set.  If any item is not yet part of a set
>       in X, it is added to X as one of the members of the merged set.
>     """
>
>     def __init__(self):
>         """Create a new empty union-find structure."""
>         self.weights = {}
>         self.parents = {}
>
>     def __getitem__(self, object):
>         """Find and return the name of the set containing the object."""
>
>         # check for previously unknown object
>         if object not in self.parents:
>             self.parents[object] = object
>             self.weights[object] = 1
>             return object
>
>         # find path of objects leading to the root
>         path = [object]
>         root = self.parents[object]
>         while root != path[-1]:
>             path.append(root)
>             root = self.parents[root]
>
>         # compress the path and return
>         for ancestor in path:
>             self.parents[ancestor] = root
>         return root
>
>     def __iter__(self):
>         """Iterate through all items ever found or unioned by this structure."""
>         return iter(self.parents)
>
>     def union(self, *objects):
>         """Find the sets containing the objects and merge them all."""
>         roots = [self[x] for x in objects]
>         heaviest = max([(self.weights[r],r) for r in roots])[1]
>         for r in roots:
>             if r != heaviest:
>                 self.weights[heaviest] += self.weights[r]
>                 self.parents[r] = heaviest
> ```

---

The Kattis online judge reports that this solution runs in 1.67 seconds, which is under the 2-second time limit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's a bug if I understood the rules. This is now a "yes" even though it should be a "wait what?":

```
2
aaa not aa
a is aa
```

This happens because `rhyme_map` does not necessarily map each word to the shortest possible rhyme. The fix is simply to change `short_words` from `set` to `list` and add a `break` to the loop that iterates over it. There is no reason for it to be a `set` anyway as it is only accessed by iteration.

Also, `rhyme_map` would seem simpler to me if, instead of testing different short words with `ends_with`, we would look up every suffix of every word:

```
def rhyme_map(rules, word_suffix_len=3):
    words = set(chain.from_iterable(chain.from_iterable(rules.values())))
    abbreviations = {}
    for word in words:
        for suffix_len in range(1, len(word)):
            suffix = word[-suffix_len:]
            if suffix in words:
                 abbreviations[word] = suffix
                 break
    return abbreviations
```